# SQL Server database population pre-existing Data Table and fields (FORM). NO database file

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

Here is my general understanding of database from what I read so far: Save / Update / Delete to pre-existing file made that binds to form thru SQL.

Here is what I am trying to do - I have a pre-made Data Table in Form with all columns defined. Once app is closed or certain functions ran, I need that data to be saved / updated in SQL (on local). Once app is open I need all that data to be preserved.

So far I have NOT found a single solution to it anywhere most refer to binding to an existing file. When I worked with Excel data transfer cells had to be defined and referenced in form for population.

My assumption is when a database from VB.NET is used, table with values can be created automatically saved/loaded/updated. However this is only my assumption since I never worked with SQL before. I am not sure if I need to manage an actual database file I created with all the values and then bind them to data table. For example DataTable cell XX to database column XX.

Here is what I done so far I have created database and added to my project. I tried few codes and I keep getting Dataset Empty even though there is Data in Table I tried to use DataTable as well but so far nothing has worked.

Please suggest on what I am doing wrong also additional information regards to databases will be great. As per previous I do know how binding works when actual file exist. But creating and managing is confusing to me since I keep thinking there should be a binding file.

```
 Dim connetionString As String
 Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
 Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
 Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
 Dim ds As New DataSet

 Dim sql As String

    connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data_Ant.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    sql = "SELECT BN FROM DataTable" ' BN is my column name and DataTable is the name of my Table where data gets populated. This is also confusing to me How does it know which value is what? Is there are space/word/characters requirements? 
    ' adapter.TableMappings.Add("DataTable", sql)

    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            sqlCnn.Open()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn)
            adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
            adapter.Update(ds)
            adapter.Dispose()
            sqlCmd.Dispose()
            sqlCnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection !" & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
        End Try
    ElseIf ds.Tables.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Empty data")
    End If
End Sub
```

Code I use to Create /Save Database. As per previous all columns/formats are pre-made, loaded.

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim sql As String

    connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data_Ant.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    sql = "Select BN FROM DataTable" 
    adapter.TableMappings.Add("BN", sql)


    If DataTable.RowCount > 0 Then
        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            sqlCnn.Open()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn)
            adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
            adapter.Update(ds, "BN")

            adapter.Dispose()
            sqlCmd.Dispose()
            sqlCnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection !" & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
        End Try
    ElseIf DataTable.RowCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Empty data")
    End If
End Sub
```

Please see more info below:

- Data Table columns/format are structured for visual representation.
- When User start the App Database can be empty/Can contain Values.
- When users Runs certain function Closes App values are save and only values.
  If I would you an MS Access I would structure same table/values and cross reference it with form values. Form Values come from outside source and Format/Qty is always known. 
  Hope this helps to have a cleaner look at my issue. Perhaps SQL is not a right choice for me? Does SQL needs to be build before value manipulation.

UPDATE: I Got rid of the Invalid Object error. Table had to be created 1st as I originally thought. However, My DataSet always comes up as EMPTY when I try to save... Cells do contain BN data as" 1,2, ....) Even if I to remove "If" logic Save and Load table comes out as empty. Something does load because when I try to ADD BN it tells me binding bla bla bla(different issue)

CODE:

```
Private Sub SaveData()

    Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data_Ant.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT BN FROM DataTable_d"
    Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    adapter.TableMappings.Add("BN", sql)

    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            sqlCnn.Open()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn)
            adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
            adapter.Update(ds, "BN")

            adapter.Dispose()
            sqlCmd.Dispose()
            sqlCnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection !" & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
        End Try
    ElseIf ds.Tables.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Empty data")
    End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE: I got all the things working but I can't save multiple rows..... Could really use some help

Comment: Do you have Sql Server Management Studio installed? (SSMS) Can you see your database in SSMS? BTW it is free for the download and will help you test Sql statements against your database.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with just displaying some data. Add a DataGridView to a Form. You can call LoadData() from a button. I am not very sure of you connection string but give it a try.

```vb
Private dt As DataTable
Private sql As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data_Ant.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

Private Sub LoadData()
    '***EDIT***  Add instantiation line
    dt = New DataTable()
    'The Using...End Using blocks will close and dispose your database objects
    'even if there is an error
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(sql)
        'You can pass the command text and the connection directly to the constructor
        'In the select statement use the actual names of the field and table as they appear in the database.
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select BN From [Insert the name of the table in the database]", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

This is the simplest way I can think of to display data. We will proceed with changing the data once this works. If you get an error on `cn.Open()` We will have to work on the connection string.

****EDIT****

```
Private Sub TestConnection()
    Dim sql As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data_Ant.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(sql)
        cn.Open()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194793/discussion-on-answer-by-mary-sql-server-database-population-pre-existing-data-ta).

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query remove `WHERE DataTable ='`. This statement is looking for a column name `DataTable` which I assume does not exist.  The WHERE clause is used to help filter your query. You only use WHERE on column names in your table.

For instance:

```
SELECT BN FROM DataTable
```

will return all values from the BN column from DataTable.

Note that if you have multiple columns, the above query will still only return values from BN.

```
SELECT * FROM DataTable
```

will return every value in DataTable.

A helpful site to look at documentation for SQL is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I posted a slightly OLD code since I don't have "WHERE" anymore. I will update it now to avoid confusion. I have reviewed the link "SqlBulkCopy" I s actually 1st method I tried to use but it simply copies bulk data from on source to another and structures it accordingly. Unfortunately this is NOT what I am looking for. I bet with MS Access this would be a walk in the park.... As per previous my database can be empty/values. Only data fields need to be updated. Sometimes initial/start of Form Database can be empty.

Comment: @Alek Actually Sql Server although much more sophisticated than Access is easier to deal with.

Comment: I was hoping so:) I never worked with SQL, none of the Apps I wrote required this previously. So I thought it be fun to learn.... so far not much :(

Comment: Each database has its own quirks but what you are learning is ADO.net which is used to access any database. so you will be able to use these skills anywhere .net framework is available.